# Как инициализировать массив указателей на символы?

Tags: c, указатели

В книге "Язык программирования Си" приведен такой пример кода:

```
char *month_name(int n)
{
    static char *name[] = {
    "Неверный месяц",
    "Январь","Февраль","Март","Апрель","Май","Июнь", 
    "Июль","Август","Сентябрь","Октябрь","Ноябрь","Декабрь"
    };

    return (n ‹ 1 || n › 12) ? name[0] : name[n];
}
```

При копировании этого кода в Visual Studio, возникает ошибка:

```
значение типа "const char*" нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа "char"
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, что это означает. И как в Си можно инициализировать массив указателей на символы?

Comment: `static const char *name[] = ...`

Обратите внимание на `const`. 

Только вот вы компилируете этот код как C++, а не как код С, несмотря на тэг "с". Потому как в режиме C в Visual C++ все это компилируется без ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> char *month_name(int n)
> ```

```
const char *month_name(int n)
```

> ```
> static char *name[] = {
> ```

```
static const char *name[] = {
```

> ```
> return (n ‹ 1 || n › 12) ? name[0] : name[n];
> ```

А тут скобки не нужны. К тому же, гораздо удобнее запизнуть условный оператор внутрь:

```
return name[n ‹ 1 || n › 12 ? 0 : n];
```